# how to remove "This question is for testing whether or not you are a human visitor and to prevent automated spam submissions" of captcha

Tags: drupal, webforms, captcha, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

**""This question is for testing whether or not you are a human visitor and to prevent automated spam submissions""**
Hi, Im looking for a way to remove this text from captcha section or change it to another text with another language.
Im using the captcha module on drupal 9 with webform,  and I don't want this text to be shown in the captcha section.
Thanks for helping me in advance
[An image from captcha section that I'm talking about could help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4T9J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend using the Drupal Translate module, so if you do not have that enabled; make sure it is.

Next, as an Administrator role, try going to: `/admin/config/regional/translate`

From there you can search the entire string that you are getting:
`This question is for testing whether or not you are a human visitor and to prevent automated spam submissions.`

You will be able to select the different languages to translate.
Make sure to update the string at least twice here.

First have it set for English (same value it's showing) and then all the other languages you are using on the website.

I did find a [source on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha/issues/2925836) that has more information related to this issue, just for your reference.